# Лягушки и их счастливые номера

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, любой-язык

Немножко про условие задачи : *Дано N лягушек и бесконечное поле, в каждой лягушки есть свой счастливый порядковый номер*. Лягушки приходят по очереди (1..N) они смотрят на клетку с номером 0, если она не занята то занимают ее, иначе перескакивают в клетку 0 + A[i], где **A[i] - счастливый порядковый номер i-той лягушки**, и повторяют этот процесс пока клетка *не будет свободной*.

Необходимо определить для каждой лягушки ее номер на бесконечном поле.

Пример:

```
6
2 3 2 4 4 6
```

Ответ:

```
0 3 2 4 8 6
```

Объяснение:

1. 1-я лягушка посмотрела на клетку с номером 0, она не занята, она ее заняла.
2. 2-я лягушка посмотрела на клетку с номером 0, она занята, перескочила на номер 3, не занята, она ее заняла.
3. 3-я лягушка заняла клетку с номером 2 по аналогии с 2-й лягушкой.
4. 4-я лягушка посмотрела на клетку номером 0, она занята, перескочила в клетку с номером 4, и заняла там своё место.
5. 5-я лягушка посмотрела на клетку номером 0, она занята, перескочила в клетку с номером 4, она занята, перескочила в клетку с номером 8 и заняла ее.
6. 6-я лягушка посмотрела на клетку номером 0, она занята, перескочила в клетку с номером 6, и заняла там своё место.

Какбы простая-то загадка, но ограничения большие:

```
1 <= N <= 3 * 10^5
1 <= A[i] <= 10^9

Ограничение по времени: 3 секунды
Ограничение по памяти: 256 МБ
```

**Моя попытка была следующей:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ll n;
    cin >> n;

    set <ll> a;

    ll x;
    for (ll i = 0;i < n;i++) 
    {
        cin >> x;
        ll c = 0;
        if (a.size() == 0) {
            a.insert(0);
            cout << 0 << " ";
            continue;
        }
        while (a.find(c) != a.end()) c += x;
        a.insert(c);
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Но увы это решение не прошло по времени :(

Comment: Для начала не set<int>, а unordered_set<uint64_t>. unordered_set сильно быстрее, а результат может достигать 3*10^14, что в int явно не влезет.

Comment: оно вообще никак не ускорило, надо другой алгоритм решения (

Comment: Попробуй развязать потоки ввода\вывода: cin.tie(nullptr);
ios_base :: sync_with_stdio (false);

Comment: спасибо, но, я уже ранее писал что нужно другой алгоритм, сейчас напишу ограничения на время и память :)

Comment: Если не понятное условие задачи пишите всем отвечу

Comment: а вывод у вас точно правильный, а то в примере не так

Comment: Только что проверил, вывод один в один с примером

Comment: я про то что ввод и вывод в одном цикле, может надо сначала вычитать числа, а потом отдельно реультаты

Comment: понятно, можно и в одном цикле выводить тестирующая система ето позволяет :)

Comment: 300000 чисел не успевает за 3 секунды, вы уверены?

Comment: вот это жрёт очень много времени -->> while (a.find(c) != a.end()) c += x )) Если будёт массив из 3 * 10^5 единиц, то эта штука ооочень долго будёт искать чтото вроде даже N^2

Comment: @Cerbo Алгоритм в худшем случае квадратичен - 300000 одинаковых чисел дадут 10^11 итераций.

Comment: Может 2 и 3 лягушки заняли 2 и 3 клетку? Чет запутало меня, про алгоритм даже не спрашивайте меня))

Comment: что то не понял сути вопроса, если про пример, то 2я лягушка заняла 3е место на поле, а 3я лягушка - 2е место на бесконечном поле

Comment: а где проверяешь?

Comment: если не смущает, что это украинский сайт, то ловите https://algotester.com/en/ArchiveProblem/Display/40605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Увидел тег `любой-язык` и поленился писать на плюсах...

- 40мс - когда у всех 300 000 лягушек одинаковое счастливое число
- 130мс - когда у 300 000 лягушек случайные счастливые числа от 1 до 10^9

Алгоритм на C#:

```
int[] Frogs(int[] frogs)
{
    // Тут храним минимальное число шагов, которые придется сделать очередной лягушке
    var steps = new Dictionary<int, int>(frogs.Length);

    // Все, кроме нулевой лягушки сделают как минимум 1 шаг
    for (int i = 1; i < frogs.Length; i++)
        steps[frogs[i]] = 1;

    // Нулевая лягушка всегда будет в нулевой клетке => ноль шагов
    steps[frogs[0]] = 0;

    // Это клетки нашего поля
    var field = new HashSet<int>(frogs.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < frogs.Length; i++)
    {
        // Вычисляем вероятно доступную ячейку
        var cell = steps[frogs[i]] * frogs[i];

        // Если она все же недоступна
        while (field.Contains(cell))
        {
            // Прыгаем дальше
            cell += frogs[i];

            // Увеличиваем счетчик шагов для данного счастливого номера
            steps[frogs[i]]++;
        }

        // Занимаем ячейку
        field.Add(cell);

        // Увеличиваем счетчик шагов для следующей лягушки
        // с таким же счастливым числом
        steps[frogs[i]]++;
    }

    // Если бы можно было вернуть IEnumerable, а не int[],
    // то можно было бы еще выиграть немного времени
    return field.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это действительно сработало :)

Answer (score 1):

Кардинально другого алгоритма не придумал, но улучшил ваш:

```
int main()
{
     using large = long long;

     long count = 0;
     std::cin >> count;

     std::vector<large> cells;   // используем вектор заместо множества
     cells.reserve(count);       // зарезвируем память заранее
     if(count)
     {
         large n = 0;
         std::cin >> n;
         std::count << 0;
         cells.push_back(0); // первая лягушка всегда занимает клетку 0,
         --count;            // продолжим со второй
     }

     large number = 0;
     while(count--)
     {
         std::cin >> number;

         const auto end = std::end(cells);
         auto place = number;
         // вначале ищем по всему вектору от начала до конца
         auto cell  = std::lower_bound(std::begin(cells), end, place);
         while(cell != end && *cell == place)
         {
              place += number;
              // последующие ищем от текущего до конца, то есть
              // область поиска каждый раз сужается
              cell = std::lower_bound(cell, end, place);
         }
         // вставка без выделения памяти, ее сразу зарезервировали,
         // по стоимости как memmove будет
         cells.insert(cell, place); 
         std::cout << place;
     }
}
```

Comment: Ехххх, но ето не зайшло :(